# Custom object select field in Salesforce web-to-lead form

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have a custom object in salesforce called `Classes` and I am using the `Leads` object for storing student information. I have a web-to-lead form for capturing student registrations, but I would like to have the students select which class they are registering for, from a dropdown select field.

Is that possible using the web-to-lead form, or do I have to create a custom one with SQL queries?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What's the relation between the two? Simple lookup from Lead to Class? In theory it should be many-to-many, with junction object.

From what I remember custom lookups from lead aren't available in the W2L form. Only Campaign is. And it renders to similar HTML:

```html
<label for="Campaign_ID">Campaign</label><select  id="Campaign_ID" name="Campaign_ID"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="701700000005lMn">International Electrical Engineers Association Trade Show - Mar 4-5, 2002</option>
<option value="701700000005lMl">User Conference - Jun 17-19, 2002</option>
<option value="701700000005lMk">GC Product Webinar - Jan 7, 2002</option>
<option value="701700000005lMm">DM Campaign to Top Customers - Nov 12-23, 2001</option>
</select><br>
```

So perhaps you could fake it, hand-craft similar HTML, point to your custom field, put right record ids in the options... Messy. Or consider displaying Campaigns & Campaign member stuff and then have something else (process builder? trigger?) that maps it from campaign to class.

If you have many-to-many or don't really like such workarounds - yup, looks like some code needed. Perhaps expose a Visualforce page as Site for signing up. Or - for non-technical people - Site.com might be tempting. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23252/difference-between-force-com-site-and-site-com